# How to enable legends and change style in pyqtgraph?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt5, pyqtgraph

Using pyQt5 I am continuously updating a plot with data using the self.graphicsView.clear() followed by self.graphicsView.plot() functions.

I changed the background color with the command pyqtgraph.setConfigOption('background', '#f0f0f0') before the widget is created, however, this does not apply to the legend items. The background is grey, and the legend appears black.

How do I change the style of this legend item?

I think I am implementing this wrong based upon how I reference each new plot item. I believe these need to be instantiated somehow, but the instance = self.graphicsView.plot(title = "example title") then referencing with instance.LegendItem and then access it with an HTML like tag. (Unable to find the reference anymore)

```
def plotGraph(self, value):
    """
    plots value to graph
    """
    self.graphQueue(self.plotDataBuffer, value)                   #buffered data input, max vals = value
    self.graphicsView.clear()                                     #clear data for continuous plot
    self.graphicsView.addLegend()
    self.graphicsView.plot(self.plotDataBuffer, pen='r', name='Data')   #plot item
```

Note: This function is called in a loop

The addLengend() command creates a new legend each time it is called, however, my understanding is that this is only created once and if it is called again it only references the legend that was already created?

So, how do i properly initialize the legends once, and then format the style to match the background instead of black?

**Simplified example:**

```
import pyqtgraph as pg
from PyQt5 import QtGui
import numpy as np
import sys

pg.setConfigOption('background', '#f0f0f0')

plotWidget = pg.plot(title="Stackoverflow Simplified Example")

app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)

while(1):
    x = np.arange(50)
    y = np.random.normal(size=(3, 50))
    plotWidget.clear()
    plotWidget.addLegend()
    for i in range(3):
        plotWidget.plot(x, y[i], pen=(i,3), name = "test {}".format(i))
    app.processEvents()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    if (sys.flags.interactive != 1) or not hasattr(QtCore, 'PYQT_VERSION'):
        app.exec_()  # Start QApplication event loop ***
```

Comment: provide  a [mre]

Comment: The only way I've found to do this is by manually editing the LegendItem.py.

Answer (score 0):

Checking the pyqtgraph LegendItem.py, one would find that the color is hard-coded into the paint function. You can replace that function with your user-defined function and change the color.

```
import pyqtgraph as pg
from PyQt5 import QtGui
import numpy as np
import sys
import types
pg.setConfigOption('background', '#f0f0f0')

plotWidget = pg.plot(title="Stackoverflow Simplified Example")

app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
leg = plotWidget.addLegend()

# replace legend paint
def paint(self, p, *args):
   p.setPen(pg.mkPen(255,0,0,100))
   p.setBrush(pg.mkBrush(0,200,0,50))
   p.drawRect(self.boundingRect())
leg.paint = types.MethodType(paint,leg)

plotData = [0]*3
for i in range(3):
   plotData[i] =plotWidget.plot([0],[0], pen=(i,3), name = "test {}".format(i))

while(1):
    x = np.arange(50)
    y = np.random.normal(size=(3, 50))
    for i in range(3):
      plotData[i].setData(x, y[i])
    app.processEvents()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    if (sys.flags.interactive != 1) or not hasattr(QtCore, 'PYQT_VERSION'):
        app.exec_()  # Start QApplication event loop ***
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you're wondering how to change the background color of a legend. Or at least that's how I stumbled upon this question.

I found that we can use the brush argument:

```
plotWidget.addLegend(brush=pg.mkBrush(255, 255, 255, 100))
```

where the first three values are your RGB color code and the last number is the alpha value that determines how transparent the background will be. In this example, the legend will be made with a white, somewhat transparent background.